# Unable to run app in Simulator XCode 6.0

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, ios-simulator

After migrating from XCode 5.0 to XCode 6.0 the project fails to run with the following error.

```
An error was encountered while running (Domain = FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain,
Code = 4)
```

Any suggestions?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: and you cleaned your project and deleted the file from your simulator before building and running it under Xcode 6, right?

Comment: I get such error with xcode 6 sometimes. Everytime fix it by closing simulator and xcode and reopen, and also reset content and settings of the simulator. But in your case I also advice you to clean derivved data of your project in xcode->orgaziner.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann had the same problem, none of delete the file, clean the project, or delete the derived folder had any affect - it was only when I did what the selected answer suggested that I was able to run my app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulator error FBSSystemServiceDomain code 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24763743/simulator-error-fbssystemservicedomain-code-4)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

iOS Simulator -> Reset Contents and Settings

Worked for me!

iOS Simulator -> Reset Contents and Settings... -> Reset

[image]

referenced from:
http://qiita.com/tajihiro/items/f6f50b56162c93d25c90

Comment: Yup - did it for me too. BTW, if you trip on this answer, will you PLEASE upvote the original question - the poor guy has a negative value now, and he even awarded an answer! This Q&A saved me oodles of time!!!

Comment: Work fine with me! Save much time.

Comment: Never had to do that before. Must be a bug in the simulator.

Comment: had the same error and this worked for me, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this error too.
My solution was product->clean

Comment: Did not do it for me. I also had previously deleted the derived folder.

Comment: Do "Clean build folder...". Select Product menu while pressing option/alt key.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [my answer to the queation that this is a duplicate of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24763743/simulator-error-fbssystemservicedomain-code-4/26950213#26950213), this error is one manifestation of an install/launch race condition bug.  The suggestions you find on this forum suggesting that you should "Erase Contents & Settings" or "Clean" from within Xcode are not correct.

You simply have to try again and hope you don't loose the race on the next launch.  Alternatively, you can just "finger launch" it from within the booted simulator.

Answer (score -2):

I had this error.

I got it while using Xcode 6 on Yosemite.

My solution was to download and install Xcode 6.1 for Yosemite. This solved my issue.

- David

Comment: As of now, there is no Xcode 6.1 listed under the iOS Developer program.