# Unable to run app in Simulator with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios-simulator

I keep trying to run an app through Xcode 6.1.1 but whenever I try it, iOS Simulator opens up to a black box, and then when I quit it I get the error:

```
Unable to run app in Simulator
An error was encountered while running (Domain = com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, Code = 146)
```

The part that is annoying is that I haven't changed any of the code after creating a new project (using a single view application). The only things I've changed are some of the settings and pictures in Main.storyboard. (These changes were just adding images to the view controller).

I've tried restarting, resetting the content and settings, and cleaning in Xcode. Any ideas on what I should do?

Comment: Related (any one could be a duplicate since we don't know what the versions are): [Unable to run app in simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26396166/608639), [Unable to run app in Simulator XCode 6.0](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25818410/608639), [Unable to run app in Simulator : Xcode beta 6 iOS 8](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24033417/608639), [Unable to run app in Simulator Xcode 6](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25608943/608639), ...

Comment: Since you've tried all those, try deleting `Derived data` http://stackoverflow.com/a/25609137/2143387

Comment: that still didn't work, getting the same error

Comment: None of the issues linked to by jww are related to this one.  Those are all completely different errors.  This is only the second time I've seen *this* error reported (and the other time, the reporter never responded, so I'm not sure if it just went away or something).  Can you please take a look a ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log while reproducing the error.  There should be more details in that log about the problem that aren't printed in the Xcode dialog box.

Comment: Dec 18 19:57:15 MacBook-Pro.local CoreSimulatorService[713] <Error>: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=146 "Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown" UserInfo=0x7fdbb2d1a4e0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown}
Dec 18 19:57:15 MacBook-Pro.local CoreSimulatorService[713] <Error>: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=146 "Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown" UserInfo=0x7fdbb2d1a4e0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown}

Comment: that's what I got from the CoreSimulator.log file

Comment: I've also gotten this:

Comment: Dec 18 18:12:50 MacBook-Pro.local CoreSimulatorService[713] <Notice>: The runtime is not available at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk

Answer (score 1):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26396166/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator), try the following Xcode menu items (under Product):

1. Clean
2. Clean build folder

You can also go to Help and start typing "Clean" in the search bar.