# FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode6, simulator

Running application in Simulator and getting the following error in Xcode 6[image]

Comment: try to reset simulator  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967606/fbsopenapplicationerrordomain-code-4-error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulator error FBSSystemServiceDomain code 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24763743/simulator-error-fbssystemservicedomain-code-4)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use stable version of Xcode 6.1.1.

```
FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain, code =4 error suggests it is an error from 
cached data on the simulator.
```

There are three possible solutions :

1. Clean simulator. Use (**Command + Shift + k)** as shortcut key or goto **Product -> Clean**
2. **Quit simulator** and relaunch it.
3. Open simulator. Select iOS simulator -> **Reset contents and settings...**

Option 3 worked for me.

[image: Screenshot for step 3]

Comment: Reset contents and settings in simulator works. But even in XCode 6.1.1 the issue occurs..